# Sum values in cfloop

Tags: loops, coldfusion, cfloop

I am referring to a previous SO [Coldfusion Calculate Sum Total (Loop? )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830784/coldfusion-calculate-sum-total-loop) that was marked as a correct answer, but the code doesn't work for me.

I am trying to create a grand total from several fields. But the error I receive is that "Variable xxx is not defined". This is because I am trying to append values from the loop for all the records

```
<cfoutput>
<cfquery name="ActivityReceipts" dbtype="query">
    SELECT
          activity,
          qty_approved,
          location,
          payment_amount, 
          shipping_cost,
          handling_cost 
   FROM   rc.RC1
   WHERE  id_number = '#Receipts.id_number#'
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="ActivityReceipts">
<tr>
<td style="text-align:left;">#ActivityReceipts.activity#</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">#ActivityReceipts.qty_approved#</td>
<td style="text-align:left;">#ActivityReceipts.location#</td>
<td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 80px;">#ActivityReceipts.payment_amount#</td>
</tr>

<cfset grandTotal =  grandTotal + ( #ActivityReceipts.payment_amount# + #ActivityReceipts.handling_cost# + #ActivityReceipts.Shipping_cost# ) />

</cfloop>


<td>#grandTotal#</td>
</cfoutput>
```

Note that if I change the grandTotal variable setting line to

```
<cfset grandTotal =  ( #ActivityReceipts.payment_amount# + #ActivityReceipts.handling_cost# + #ActivityReceipts.Shipping_cost# ) />
```

it does not cause an error, but it also only sums the last row, rather than all of them.

Comment: Nothing to do with your error, but there is no need to wrap the `cfquery` in a `cfoutput`, only the html portion. #Variables# inside the query tag will be evaluated automatically. Also, do not forget to use `cfqueryparam` to protect against sql injection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize `grandTotal` like so:

```
<cfset grandTotal = 0>
<cfloop query="ActivityReceipts">
    <tr>
        <td style="text-align:left;">#ActivityReceipts.activity#</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;">#ActivityReceipts.qty_approved#</td>
        <td style="text-align:left;">#ActivityReceipts.location#</td>
        <td style="text-align: right; padding-right: 80px;">
            #ActivityReceipts.payment_amount#
       </td>
   </tr>

   <cfset grandTotal =  grandTotal + ( ActivityReceipts.payment_amount 
                                       + ActivityReceipts.handling_cost 
                                       + ActivityReceipts.Shipping_cost 
                                   ) />
</cfloop>
```

Comment: use `PrecisionEvaluate()` if you care about rounding error!  Otherwise, use `+=` to make your code look cooler. :)

Answer (score 5):

you need to set a default for the grandtotal var before the loop...

```
<cfset grandTotal = 0>
```

Also, you don't need to put pound signs if you aren't going to output or quote the var.

```
<cfset grandTotal =  grandTotal + ( ActivityReceipts.payment_amount + ActivityReceipts.handling_cost + ActivityReceipts.Shipping_cost ) />
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to do it without a loop.

```
grandTotal = ArraySum(ActivityReceipts["payment_amount"])
+ ArraySum(ActivityReceipts["handling_cost"])
+ ArraySum(ActivityReceipts["Shipping_cost"]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define and initialize the variable `grandTotal` before you can do a statement like `<cfset grandTotal =  grandTotal + ...`. Just do something like:

```
  ...
</cfquery>

<cfset grandTotal= 0>

<cfloop query="ActivityReceipts">
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with `<cfset grandtotal=0>` before your loop.  Since you reference it in your loop, and its not initialized, you're getting undefined.