# How can I use dynamically generated variables from cfloop individually?

Tags: coldfusion, cfloop

I'm not sure my title explains this very well. Frankly, I'm not sure how to put it into words, but here goes:

I am capturing variables from dynamically created form fields on another page, that have been submitted to a page containing the code below. So far, everything works as I want it to. I'm getting the dynamically named form fields. Now I need to add the subtotal dollar amounts together to create a grand total. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to get the individual totals out of the loop so I can do the math for the final number, due to their dynamic nature.

This part of the code below generates the subtotals, and I need to be able to add all of them together to get a grand total, but I can't figure out how:

```
#dollarformat(val(getticket[item].ticketprice * form[item]))#
```

Maybe I need to take a different approach...suggestions/help appreciated.

Here's the full code:

```
<CFLOOP LIST="#form.fieldnames#" INDEX="item">
<cfoutput>

    <cfquery datasource="outertixdb" name="getticket[item]">
        select * from tickets
        where ticketid = '#item#'
    </cfquery>

    #getticket[item].ticketname#: #dollarformat(getticket[item].ticketprice)# x #form[item]# = #dollarformat(val(getticket[item].ticketprice * form[item]))#<br/>

</cfoutput>
```

Comment: is `getticket[item]` a reference to a variable or are you trying to concatenate the word getticket with your item, so the query is called `getticket1` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I completely understand, but it sounds like you are simply trying to look up a bunch of ticket records, by "id". Then display the individual costs, plus a grand total. If that is all your doing, just give the fields the *same* name: `ticketID`. For example:

```
  <input name="ticketID" value="1" ...>
  <input name="ticketID" value="22" ...>
  <input name="ticketID" value="45" ...>
  <input name="ticketID" value="16" ...>
```

Then the values will be submitted as a list ie `1,22,45,16`, which you can feed into your query using an IN clause. That lets you grab all of the data in a single query. (Generally you want to avoid running queries within a loop because performing a separate database query for *each* id generates a lot of unnecessary overhead and degrades performance).

<sub>* Change the cfsqltype as needed</sub>

```
SELECT TicketID, TicketPrice
FROM   YourTable
WHERE  TicketID IN ( <cfquerparam value="#FORM.ticketID#" 
                             list="true" 
                             cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer"> 
                  )
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> `form[item]` is the value of the quantity select from the previous page.

That is a confusing naming convention. I would recommend using a slightly more intuitive name like "quantity". Something more descriptive of the contents. You can still use the ticket id to generate unique names, ie `quantity_#ticketID#`. For example, using the same ticket id's as above:

```
  <input name="quantity_1" ...>
  <input name="quantity_22" ...>
  <input name="quantity_45" ...>
  <input name="quantity_16" ...>
```

Once you have the results, there are [several ways to generate a grand total](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7830784/coldfusion-calculate-sum-total-loop). The simplest being to initialize a variable before your loop, then increment it as you iterate. Use the query ticket ID to grab the quantity value from the FORM scope:

```
 <cfset grandTotal = 0>
 <cfoutput query="yourQuery">
     <!--- extract quantity value --->
     <cfset currQuantity = FORM["quantity_"& yourQuery.ticketID ]>
     ... display price ...
     <cfset grandTotal += val(yourQuery.ticketPrice * currQuantity )> 
 </cfoutput>

 GrandTotal <cfoutput>#grandTotal#</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Hey, I saw you deleted your answer on the other thread. I was hoping to go over that and possibly reconsider the entire structure of the ticket site. I honestly believe you might be on to something, and want to present your ideas to the powers that be. If you can put it back, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to set the `name` attribute of your `cfquery` using the following format:

```
<cfquery datasource="outertixdb" name="#getticket[item]#">
```

To handle the total, you would first need a variable before the `cfloop`

```
<cfset total = 0 />
```

Then, inside the loop, you simply add the price of the ticket to the total

```
<cfset total = total + getticket[item].ticketprice />
```

Also, you should be using `cfqueryparam` in your query. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam)

Lastly, if you do not need all the data in the `tickets` table, do not use 'select *..', only pull pack the data that you need.

Comment: I'd also add that a rethink might be in order if one is hitting the DB repeatedly in a loop. There will be a better way to fetch the data so that the DB is only hit once.

Comment: This works, but now I'm concerned about the query inside the loop, and I'm not fully understanding Leigh's suggestion.

Comment: @JoeNobody if you're running one query it wouldn't be inside the loop. Your loop would be running through the contents of your query.

Comment: One more problem. This is not totaling the right numbers. I need the result of all the numbers created by: #dollarformat(val(getticket[item].ticketprice * form[item]))#

Comment: Ok. Solved that by doing this inside the loop:
<cfset grandtotal = val(grandtotal + getticket[item].ticketprice * form[item]) />

Comment: @JoeNobody - What is the value of `form[item]`? You seem to be using it as an "ID" value in the query, but then the code multiplies the price by this "id" .. which is odd. I would have expected you to multiply by a "quantity" or similar. (Edit) See my updated response for a fuller example of how to pass the id's.

Comment: @Leigh - Actually, form[item] is the value of the quantity select from the previous page. So, it IS the quantity. I get the ID from the actual select name (which, again, is dynamically created on the previous page).

Comment: @JoeNobody - Oh, that is a confusing naming convention. I would recommend making it more intuitive, like `FORM.quantity_#theTicketID#`. Then you could combine it with my earlier suggestion and improve the query efficiency. When you display the query results, use query ticket ID value to grab the quantity from the FORM scope, something like `<cfset currPrice = val(yourQuery.ticketID * FORM["quantity_"& yourQuery.ticketID)>`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend throwing out the whole dynamically named query thing.

```
<cfset total = 0>

<CFLOOP LIST="#form.fieldnames#" INDEX="item">

    <cfquery datasource="outertixdb" name="getticket">
       select * from tickets
       where ticketid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#item#">
    </cfquery>

 <cfset total += getticket.ticketprice />    


 <cfoutput query="getTicket">   
    #ticketname#: #dollarformat(ticketprice)# &times; #form[item]# 
    = #dollarformat(val(ticketprice * form[item]))#<br/>
</cfoutput>
</cfloop>
```

Output your total as needed